# Optimize Uniform Transmission

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, opengl, optimization

I'm working on an OpenGL renderer in C++, but I ran into a massive performance problem. The way I am setting Uniforms is I push the uniform value to a material class that stores all of the pushed uniforms in an `std::map`. I then have to loop over all of the uniforms I pushed to check what type of uniform it is and then send the uniform to the shader program. It's incredibly slow and CPU usage is greatly increased from ~9% to over 20%. The obvious way to fix this is to not store the uniforms and just send them in the renderer, but material specific uniforms can't be sent like that because every object has a different material. Here's the code that I run to set the uniforms:

```cpp
void Material::SetUniforms(){
    for(auto it = pm_textures.begin(); it != pm_textures.end(); it++){
        switch(it->second.type){
            case UTYPE_SAMPLERCUBE:
                std::get<Cubemap*>(it->second.texture)->Bind(it->second.slot);
                break;
            default:
                std::get<Texture*>(it->second.texture)->Bind(it->second.slot);
                break;
        }
    }

    for(auto it = pm_uniforms.begin(); it != pm_uniforms.end(); it++){
        switch(it->second.type){
            case UTYPE_INT:
                pm_shader->SetUniform1i(it->first, std::get<int>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_FLOAT:
                pm_shader->SetUniform1f(it->first, std::get<float>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_VEC2:
                pm_shader->SetUniformVec2(it->first, std::get<glm::vec2>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_VEC3:
                pm_shader->SetUniformVec3(it->first, std::get<glm::vec3>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_VEC4:
                pm_shader->SetUniformVec4(it->first, std::get<glm::vec4>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_MAT2:
                pm_shader->SetUniformMat2(it->first, std::get<glm::mat2>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_MAT3:
                pm_shader->SetUniformMat3(it->first, std::get<glm::mat3>(it->second.value));
                break;
            case UTYPE_MAT4:
                pm_shader->SetUniformMat4(it->first, std::get<glm::mat4>(it->second.value));
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Material : unknown uniform type" << std::endl; 
                break;
        }
    } 
}
```

I need a better way to set all of the uniforms because this way is very hard on my system.

Comment: It's not clear if you have different programs that need to share uniforms or which uniforms are grouped with which others, or what specifically is going on. Overall, you need to use UBOs, but how best to employ them relies on details not present in your question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I looked into using UBOs, but I notice a problem with using them. My problem isn't with global values, it's with values that are different for every object and therefor change frequently. Materials share shaders, so shaders are only needed to be loaded once, so when the object being rendered changes, the uniform values change. I don't think UBOs would work very well for my situation. I'm not entirely sure how UBOs work though, because I've never heard about them until now, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @User-92You can source all material-related uniforms via a separate UBO, which means you just need each material to manage it's own UBO, and you just need to bind the respective UBO when rendering with the material.