# Get Names of Uniforms in Uniform Block

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, buffer

So I asked this question: [Optimize Uniform Transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71373605/optimize-uniform-transmission), and was suggested to use Uniform Buffers. I did some research and tried to implement it, but ran into a problem with loading the format of the Uniform Blocks from the shader. In my project, I have a shader class that loads all of the uniforms, vertex attributes and stores them in the shader so the user can easily change the values without the positions of the uniforms having to be queried from the shader again. I am trying to do the same with the uniform blocks, but I don't now how to retrieve all the data I need.

This is the type of data I am trying to get from the shader:

1. Uniform Block Name
2. Uniform Block Size
3. Uniform Block Index
4. The Names of All The Uniforms in The Uniform Block

My main issue is with the last one. To use for example, this is my uniform block:

```c
uniform MatBlock{
    vec4 MatColor;
    int MatRoughness;
} material;
```

I want to be able to get a map of the names of the uniforms, so `{"MatColor":0, "MatRoughness":16}`, the second value is the offset for the uniform. This is so the offset can easily be fetched and set. My goal is to be able to do something like `uniformbuffer->PushData(0.3f, sizeof(float), "MaterialBlock", "MatRoughness");`, so this would set MatRoughness to 0.3 in the UBO. I already have code to get the first 3 items in the list (code located below), but I can't figure out how to get the names.

```cpp
glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_BLOCKS, &numblocks);        
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numblocks; i++){
    // Get the name of the uniform block
    int namelen;
    glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(shader, i, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_NAME_LENGTH, &namelen); 
    char blockname[namelen];
    glGetActiveUniformBlockName(shader, i, namelen, NULL, blockname);
                 
    // Add Block Binding
    unsigned int index = glGetUniformBlockIndex(shader, blockname);
    glUniformBlockBinding(shader, index, i);

    // Get the size of the block
    int size;
    glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(shader, i, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE, &size);
}
```

and once I get the uniform block uniforms, how would I set the data using `glMapData`? I have this pseudo-code that I wrote for this as an example:

```cpp
void UniformBuffer::PushData(void* data, unsigned int size, std::string uniformname){
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, pm_uboid);
    void* blockptr = glMapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    mcmcpy(blockptr + pm_uniforms[uniname], data, size);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how this works because it's hard to find solid examples.

In summary:

How do get the names of all the uniforms in a uniform block and how do I update the data in a uniform block via the `glMapBuffer` command?

Comment: Grab `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_INDICES` & pass those indexes into `glGetActiveUniformName()`?

Comment: @genpfault I actually tried that, but I couldn't figure out how to save the data returned because it returns an array instead of a single value.

Comment: Query `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS` first for the number of items returned by `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_INDICES` & allocate a correspondingly sized buffer to accept the values.

Comment: @genpfault I meant how would I create the buffer to store the values?

Comment: I usually create a `std::vector<>` of the appropriate type (`GLint`)  & size (`GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS`) then pass in the pointer from `std::vector<>::data()`.

Answer (score 6):

> My goal is to be able to do something like `uniformbuffer->PushData(0.3f, sizeof(float), "MaterialBlock", "MatRoughness");`,

This is not a goal worth having. For several reasons.

In the most general sense, UBOs should *not* be treated like regular uniform values. They're data structures, ones which can map *directly* to C or C++ objects. Assuming you're using `std140` or `std430` layout (and really, there's no reason *not* to use these layouts), you can write an equivalent struct whose fields exactly map to the ones in GLSL.

So updating a UBO shouldn't be done on a value-by-value level. It should be done by uploading a struct matching the UBO. This is especially true if the structs are small. You should never have to query the layout; you should just upload an appropriately designed struct.

Furthermore, UBOs are stored in buffer objects. As such, modifying them has to be done carefully, *especially* if you're using the same buffer for multiple objects. Well, it doesn't *have* to be done carefully; you can do it however you want.

So long as you don't care about performance.

For example, mapping the buffer to modify it on a per-value level is just throwing performance away. Mapping a buffer has such a huge performance cost that they added newer functionality to allow people to map it once and never unmap it. Though once you do that, all synchronization is on you.

Exactly how you should handle this depends on what you're actually using it for. But there's pretty much no use case for this kind of API. Or at least, not a use case where there isn't a better way to do it.

And as for the API itself, it just doesn't make sense. I don't know what the `uniformBuffer` object is supposed to be, but if it is meant to encapuslate a uniform block defined in a shader, the *name* of that block ("MaterialBlock") is irrelevant. What matters is the *layout* of the block.

Also, to the extent that the block name matters... it should be stored in `uniformBuffer`, not specified by the user. That is, this `uniformBuffer`  object ought to represent a specific uniform block.

---

That being said, if you absolutely must query layout information about a UBO (and let me stress again, you should not), it can be done as follows.

All (active) uniform blocks used in a program can be queried via the [introspection API](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection). For this example, I'll be using the [newer, unified introspection API](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Interface_query).

Uniform blocks are an interface, notably named `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK`. This interface contains an array of uniform block entries, numbered 0 to the number of active uniform blocks in the program. So you need to query what that number is:

```
GLint numUniformBlocks = 0;
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(program​, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK, GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES​, &numUniformBlocks);
```

So we simply loop from 0 to `numUniformBlocks`, which loops over all of the active uniform blocks. For a particular uniform block index, you can query its name, how many uniforms are in it, and the list of those uniforms. That list will be indices into a single array of all `GL_UNIFORM`s used by that program.

```
std::array<GLenum, 3> blockProperties{GL_NAME_LENGTH, GL_NUM_ACTIVE_VARIABLES, GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE};
std::array<GLint, 3> blockData{};

for(int blockIx = 0; blockIx < numUniformBlocks; ++blockIx)
{
  glGetProgramResourceiv(program, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK, blockIx, blockProperties.size(), blockProperties.data(), blockData.size(), nullptr, blockData.data());

  //Retrieve name
  std::string blockName(blockData[0]);
  glGetProgramResourceName(program​, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK, blockIx, blockName.size() + 1, nullptr, blockName​.data());

  //Retrieve indices of uniforms that are a member of this block.
  std::vector<GLint> uniformIxs(blockData[1]);
  GLenum member = GL_ACTIVE_VARIABLES;

  glGetProgramResourceiv(program, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK, blockIx, 1, &member, uniformIxs.size(), nullptr, uniformIxs.data());

  //We already retrieved the size.
  auto bufferDataSize = blockData[2];
}
```

Having retrieved the array of uniform indices, we can now query the properties of those uniforms, like their names. So, within the above loop, we just loop over the array of uniform indices, querying from the `GL_UNIFORM` interface:

```
for(auto unifIx: uniformIxs)
{
  GLint nameLength = 0;
  GLenum nameProp = GL_NAME_LENGTH;
  glGetProgramResourceiv(program, GL_UNIFORM, unifIx, 1, &nameProp, 1, nullptr, &nameLength);

  std::string unifName(nameLength);
  glGetProgramResourceName(program​, GL_UNIFORM, unifIx, unifName.size() + 1, nullptr, unifName.data());
}
```

Where you store this data is up to you.

Comment: "updating a UBO shouldn't be done on a value-by-value level. It should be done by uploading a struct matching the UBO" I heard about this but I didn't do it like this because that would require me to make a structure like the uniform block in the shader, and I wanted it to be automatically loaded, which I don't think you can do, so I opted to change value by value and all of the values are done at once and don't change regularly throughout the program. I would still have to remap if a value changed in both ways of updating the UBO, I think.

Comment: "For this example, I'll be using the newer, unified introspection API." Does this work with version 3.3? "Also, to the extent that the block name matters... it should be stored in uniformBuffer, not specified by the user" It isn't. It's loaded from the shader. "if it is meant to encapuslate a uniform block defined in a shader" Yes, it is.